# Placing footnotes at the end of the manuscript in apa6

Tags: footnotes, apa6

I am writing a paper using the [`apa6`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6) package. I have been asked to place all of the footnotes on a separate page after the reference list. This is indeed the style that sample manuscripts in the APA's Publication Manual (6th edition) follow. In the `apa6` class, however, footnotes are placed at the bottom of the page by default rather than at the end of the manuscript. Is there a way to move all the footnotes to a separate page after the reference list? The `apa` class that is no longer maintained apparently placed all the footnotes on a separate page, and I'm wondering if I can do something similar with the `apa6`.

```
\documentclass[man, a4paper, 12pt]{apa6}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Main body.\footnote{footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote sample]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `endnotes` package:

```
\documentclass[man, a4paper, 12pt]{apa6}

\usepackage{endnotes}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\let\footnote\endnote

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Main body.\footnote{footnote}

X\footnote{Abc} \kant[1]

X\footnote{Abc} \kant[2]

X\footnote{Abc} \kant[3]

\clearpage
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the footnotes should still resembles the traditional footnotes, but just on a separate page at the end of the document, you can capture each `\footnote` and replace it with a combination `\footnotemark` and *delayed* `\footnotetext`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
  \footnotemark% Leave a footnote mark and ...
  \AtEndDocument{\footnotetext{#1}}% Store \footnotetext for end-of-document
}
\let\oldfootnotetext\footnotetext
\renewcommand{\footnotetext}{\stepcounter{footnote}\oldfootnotetext}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \clearpage% Clear the page
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}% Reset the footnote counter
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]\footnote{First footnote.}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{Second footnote.}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{Third footnote.}

\lipsum[4]\footnote{Fourth footnote.}

\lipsum[5]\footnote{Fifth footnote.}

\lipsum[6]\footnote{Sixth footnote.}

\lipsum[7]\footnote{Seventh footnote.}

\lipsum[8]\footnote{Eighth footnote.}

\lipsum[9]\footnote{Ninth footnote.}

\lipsum[10]\footnote{Tenth footnote.}

\end{document}
```